# Maximum duration (or file size) of html5 video

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm trying to use a custom html5 player with a 4-hour long video (2.3 GB!), but I'm getting some problems: playback stops, video seeking doesn't seem to work well and so on.

Using the native player of the browser, I have the same issues.

So I was wondering: are there any recommendations about the maximum duration (or file size) of a video in html5? What about mobile devices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the video had some problems. I did some tests with other videos though:

- **800MB, 2h and 24m video**: everything works ok, tested with a desktop pc and an iPad 3;
- **9.7GB, 4h and 3m video**: everything works well until I get to 1h 50min (but the video was intentionally big).

But I'd still be glad to find other resources or articles talking about the issue.